# Seeing the process lnqtkqhegaq.exe on windows 7 x64. What is it?

Tags: windows-7, virus, process

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Computer is infected by a virus or a malware, what do I do now?](https://superuser.com/questions/100360/computer-is-infected-by-a-virus-or-a-malware-what-do-i-do-now)

One of my friend's yahoo account was hacked recently (the account was accessed from Mexico, Poland, Canada, Japan, and couple other countries - he's in Seattle, WA, USA). He changed the password and all the security questions, etc., but we wanted to try to find out, how they get into his account in the first place. When I opened Task Manager -> Processes, and there's a process called `lnqtkqhegaq.exe`, description: `lnqtkqhegaq`. The process starts up together with the system. **Has anyone seen this process before? How can we find and remove this process permanently?** I tried to search the whole file system for that file - no files found; run the norton with newest database - no viruses or malwares, etc. Any ideas?

Here's his configurations in case it's important:
Windows 7 64-bit, AMD Phenom II 2.2GHz, 4GB RAM. The laptop is HP G62 Notebook PC.

Comment: [Computer is infected by a virus or a malware, what do I do now?](http://superuser.com/questions/100360/computer-is-infected-by-a-virus-or-a-malware-what-do-i-do-now)

Comment: @Bob: none of the "symptoms" fit our case. Computer itself works fine. It's just that recently, 2 yahoo accounts have been hacked when used that laptop to sign in.

Comment: If all you want to do is remove it, get [autoruns](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb963902.aspx), find it, and remove it.

Comment: This is malware. It is a randomly generated filename designed to bypass detection and / or removal.

Comment: @RandolphWest: I thought malware would be detected by Norton?

Comment: @shershams Try some of the recommended ways to clean up; no single antimalware program will catch everything. Personally, I've had MalwareBytes Anti-Malware catch a whole lot Norton misses.

Comment: @shershams Norton will detect the malware IF your product is up-to-date and IF Norton has already taken into consideration this variant of malware and computed a signature for it.

Comment: @Silviu and IF the malware has not disabled or blocked Norton's scans (rootkits especially will do this) - that is why it is recommended to boot off another operating system or attach the hard drive to another computer.

Answer (score 0):

To test wheter thi is a virus you can use online virus scans against any file. Try [VirusScan from Jotti](http://virusscan.jotti.org).

If you want to clean your machine try installing some good antivirus on it. To select good antivirus I always recommand paging through some sites like [av-comparatives.org](http://av-comparatives.org), they give a good background of antivirus products quality. My all time favorite is [Avira](http://www.avira.com) and it is also available free for personal use.